# Full queue, lose event in Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm using the Android emulator running API version 15 from the SDK tools and in the console I'm getting this error:

```
[Date - Emulator] ##KBD: Full queue, lose event
```

I can't click on anything obviously. I googled it and the only solution is to delete the emulator and recreate it. This works for a while but then I have the same problem again.

Does anyone know what causes this error and how to fix it?

Answer (score 21):

You can try the following to clear the old data and applications (your emulator will return to its default settings and data)

**Tools** --> **Android** --> **AVD Manager**

Then select your Emulator

From Actions column hit the arrow and select **Wipe Data**

Answer (score 12):

I was facing same problem, There is Nothing RAM problem.

Solution is here's

Go to Tools -> AVD Manager ->Find the emulator which you are having this error -> Right click on your emulator and click on COLD BOOT NOW.

Answer (score 9):

i probably figured it out. try this:

While creating the android virtual device, you must have given its size in KIBs or upto 32 mibs as shown in one of the tutorials on web.

now delete the previous device and make a new device giving its size as 512 MIB. It solved my problem.
Hope it'll work for you also, just give it a try.

[image: can't show image]

Comment: Thanks for the advice, it works for me too! Just a hint: no need to delete the device, you can click on "Value" and change it. If emulator refuses to run, go to AVD manager and start from there with deselected "launch from snapshot". Second time you can select it again.

Answer (score 2):

I have ran into the same problem and I realized that I had dedicated only 256 MB of RAM for the virtual device. It had simply run out of memory.

Here's the solution:

-Go to Tools -> Android -> AVD Manager

-Find the emulator you are having this error on.

-Click to the "edit" button next to it. (In 3.0, this appears as a green pencil)

-Click "Show advanced settings"

-Scroll down and assign some more RAM to the device, 1GB should cut it, 2GB is definitely enough if you are running a simple app. I would also recommend assigning 512 MB of heap.

-Hit finish. Exit the emulator and restart it.

You should be good now, I hope it's been helpful. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

this is a bug in android emulators. i also had the same problem. use 64bit linux for development to minimize such issues.
** freezing problem is there on 64-bit linux machines also, but the frequency of such problems is highly reduced. also emulators behave notably faster.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I don't know whether this will help you... I had many problems when I try to run the emulator in Apple Mac mini. Whenever I run the emulator, machine asked me to restart. When contact Apple support, they told me it's a problem with less Memory. Just check and see how the memory is utilized by the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue if you not provide enough resources to your virtual device or your virtual device is stuck some how.

Any one of these solutions should work

if you don't have anything useful in your virtual device, you can wipe it. by simply going to

1. `Tools > Android > AVD Manager`
2. Then select your virtual device
3. Right click select `Wipe Data`

Each time you start a virtual device it maintain state and pre installed apps in its memory so a cold boot will also be a good option.

to cold boot simple follow first two steps from above and select `Cold Boot Now`.

[image: Android Virtual Device Manager]

Now you are good to go!