# its not showing any errors but not working not fetching the data from API

Tags: kotlin

this is the mainactivty code I use to fetch the data from Api
i think W/Gralloc3: mapper 3.x is not supported is the problem but I can't find any answer that work regarding this so can any one tell me where is the problem or how to solve the issue it will be very helpfull

```
package com.zerooes.myapplication
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import retrofit2.*
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory

lateinit var textView: TextView

const val BASE_URL="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/"
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        getMyData()
        textView=findViewById(R.id.txtId)
    }

    private fun getMyData() {
        val retrofitBuilder=Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .build()
            .create(SimpleAPI::class.java)
        val retrofitData=retrofitBuilder.getData()
        retrofitData.enqueue(object : Callback<List<MyDataItem>?> {
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<List<MyDataItem>?>,
                response: Response<List<MyDataItem>?>
            ) {
                val responseBody=response.body()!!
                println(responseBody)
                val MyStringBuilder = StringBuilder()
                for(myData in responseBody){
                    MyStringBuilder.append(myData.id)
                    MyStringBuilder.append(" \n")

                }
                textView.text= MyStringBuilder

            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<MyDataItem>?>, t: Throwable) {
                println("itfailed")
            }
        })

    }
}
```

this is MyDatafile

```
 package com.zerooes.myapplication

class MyData : ArrayList<MyDataItem>()
```

and this is MyDataItem file

```
 package com.zerooes.myapplication

data class MyDataItem(
    val body: String,
    val id: Int,
    val title: String,
    val userId: Int
)
```

this is simpleApi file

```
package com.zerooes.myapplication

import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.http.GET

interface SimpleAPI {
    @GET("posts")
    fun getData():Call<List<MyDataItem>>
}
```

this is activitymain file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and this is manifeast file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.zerooes.myapplication">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

then the build gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.zerooes.myapplication"
        minSdk 29
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildToolsVersion '33.0.0'
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    // Retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

and the output is

```
2022-09-18 23:18:45.047 11546-11546/com.zerooes.myapplication W/s.myapplicatio: Accessing hidden method Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;-><init>(Ljava/lang/Class;I)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2022-09-18 23:18:45.090 11546-11546/com.zerooes.myapplication D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2022-09-18 23:18:45.094 11546-11546/com.zerooes.myapplication W/s.myapplicatio: Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->get()Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard; (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)
2022-09-18 23:18:45.094 11546-11546/com.zerooes.myapplication W/s.myapplicatio: Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->open(Ljava/lang/String;)V (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)
2022-09-18 23:18:45.094 11546-11546/com.zerooes.myapplication W/s.myapplicatio: Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->warnIfOpen()V (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)
2022-09-18 23:18:45.107 11546-11546/com.zerooes.myapplication W/s.myapplicatio: Accessing hidden field Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->theUnsafe:Lsun/misc/Unsafe; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2022-09-18 23:18:45.108 11546-11546/com.zerooes.myapplication W/s.myapplicatio: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->allocateInstance(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2022-09-18 23:18:45.218 11546-11578/com.zerooes.myapplication D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xd1869ff0, tid 11578
2022-09-18 23:18:45.228 11546-11578/com.zerooes.myapplication D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV420_888_to_NV21 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit ANDROID_EMU_sync_buffer_data GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
2022-09-18 23:18:45.232 11546-11578/com.zerooes.myapplication W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
2022-09-18 23:18:45.254 11546-11578/com.zerooes.myapplication D/eglCodecCommon: setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
2022-09-18 23:18:45.254 11546-11578/com.zerooes.myapplication D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xdce7f360: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
2022-09-18 23:18:45.294 11546-11578/com.zerooes.myapplication D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xdce7f360: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xdcee4150)
2022-09-18 23:18:45.302 11546-11578/com.zerooes.myapplication W/Gralloc3: mapper 3.x is not supported
2022-09-18 23:18:45.305 11546-11578/com.zerooes.myapplication D/HostConnection: createUnique: call
2022-09-18 23:18:45.305 11546-11578/com.zerooes.myapplication D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xd186b8a0, tid 11578
2022-09-18 23:18:45.308 11546-11578/com.zerooes.myapplication D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV420_888_to_NV21 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit ANDROID_EMU_sync_buffer_data GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
2022-09-18 23:18:45.310 11546-11578/com.zerooes.myapplication D/eglCodecCommon: allocate: Ask for block of size 0x1000
2022-09-18 23:18:45.310 11546-11578/com.zerooes.myapplication D/eglCodecCommon: allocate: ioctl allocate returned offset 0x3ff68c000 size 0x2000
2022-09-18 23:18:45.314 11546-11578/com.zerooes.myapplication D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xdce7f360: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xdcee4150)
2022-09-18 23:18:45.317 11546-11578/com.zerooes.myapplication D/eglCodecCommon: setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 1 0
2022-09-18 23:18:45.366 11546-11546/com.zerooes.myapplication I/System.out: itfailed
2022-09-18 23:42:55.496 11895-11895/? I/s.myapplicatio: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2022-09-18 23:42:55.791 11895-11895/? E/s.myapplicatio: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2022-09-18 23:42:55.802 11895-11895/? W/s.myapplicatio: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
2022-09-18 23:42:56.301 11895-11929/com.zerooes.myapplication D/libEGL: Emulator has host GPU support, qemu.gles is set to 1.
2022-09-18 23:42:56.303 11895-11929/com.zerooes.myapplication W/libc: Unable to set property "qemu.gles" to "1": connection failed; errno=13 (Permission denied)
2022-09-18 23:42:56.323 11895-11929/com.zerooes.myapplication D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
2022-09-18 23:42:56.286 11895-11895/com.zerooes.myapplication W/RenderThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:85): avc: denied { write } for name="property_service" dev="tmpfs" ino=996 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c135,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:property_socket:s0 tclass=sock_file permissive=0
2022-09-18 23:42:56.331 11895-11929/com.zerooes.myapplication D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
2022-09-18 23:42:56.333 11895-11929/com.zerooes.myapplication D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
2022-09-18 23:42:56.503 11895-11895/com.zerooes.myapplication W/s.myapplicatio: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2022-09-18 23:42:56.504 11895-11895/com.zerooes.myapplication W/s.myapplicatio: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2022-09-18 23:42:56.591 11895-11895/com.zerooes.myapplication W/s.myapplicatio: Accessing hidden method Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;-><init>(Ljava/lang/Class;I)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2022-09-18 23:42:56.647 11895-11895/com.zerooes.myapplication D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2022-09-18 23:42:56.652 11895-11895/com.zerooes.myapplication W/s.myapplicatio: Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->get()Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard; (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)
2022-09-18 23:42:56.652 11895-11895/com.zerooes.myapplication W/s.myapplicatio: Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->open(Ljava/lang/String;)V (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)
2022-09-18 23:42:56.652 11895-11895/com.zerooes.myapplication W/s.myapplicatio: Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->warnIfOpen()V (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)
2022-09-18 23:42:56.673 11895-11895/com.zerooes.myapplication W/s.myapplicatio: Accessing hidden field Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->theUnsafe:Lsun/misc/Unsafe; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2022-09-18 23:42:56.673 11895-11895/com.zerooes.myapplication W/s.myapplicatio: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->allocateInstance(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2022-09-18 23:42:56.774 11895-11927/com.zerooes.myapplication D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xd4e57190, tid 11927
2022-09-18 23:42:56.775 11895-11927/com.zerooes.myapplication D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV420_888_to_NV21 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit ANDROID_EMU_sync_buffer_data GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
2022-09-18 23:42:56.785 11895-11927/com.zerooes.myapplication W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
2022-09-18 23:42:56.804 11895-11927/com.zerooes.myapplication D/eglCodecCommon: setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
2022-09-18 23:42:56.804 11895-11927/com.zerooes.myapplication D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xd4e1a300: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
2022-09-18 23:42:56.861 11895-11927/com.zerooes.myapplication D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xd4e1a300: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xd4e0f610)
2022-09-18 23:42:56.869 11895-11927/com.zerooes.myapplication W/Gralloc3: mapper 3.x is not supported
2022-09-18 23:42:56.870 11895-11927/com.zerooes.myapplication D/HostConnection: createUnique: call
2022-09-18 23:42:56.870 11895-11927/com.zerooes.myapplication D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xd4e57460, tid 11927
2022-09-18 23:42:56.871 11895-11927/com.zerooes.myapplication D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV420_888_to_NV21 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit ANDROID_EMU_sync_buffer_data GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
2022-09-18 23:42:56.871 11895-11927/com.zerooes.myapplication D/eglCodecCommon: allocate: Ask for block of size 0x1000
2022-09-18 23:42:56.872 11895-11927/com.zerooes.myapplication D/eglCodecCommon: allocate: ioctl allocate returned offset 0x3ff68c000 size 0x2000
2022-09-18 23:42:56.875 11895-11927/com.zerooes.myapplication D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xd4e1a300: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xd4e0f610)
2022-09-18 23:42:56.878 11895-11927/com.zerooes.myapplication D/eglCodecCommon: setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 1 0
2022-09-18 23:42:56.950 11895-11895/com.zerooes.myapplication I/System.out: itfailed
```

not a single error but the data is not fetch or displayed please help

Answer (score 0):

to solve this issue just wipe just wipedata and coldboot the emulator and it worked https://stackoverflow.com/a/49717161/20024486 and
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55361323/20024486
this is where I get that from after searching for days